# Qt: how can I make QWidget show up in more than one location on my mainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, resize, qwidget

I have a `QMainWindow` with a large number of graphs (I am using `QCustomPlot` for those). As a result, each graph is inevitably rather small in size. All the graphs in this page are drawn on the 1st page of a `QStackedWidget`.

To provide a clearer view for each graph (one at a time), I want to show a larger view of a graph when the user clicks on one. 
A potential solution is to have a 2nd page on the `QStackedWidget` in which the larger graph can be shown. The question is how do I go about assigning the selected graph to the 2nd page of a `QStackedWidget`?

Alternatively, is there a better way to enlarge a specific `QWidget` so that it occupies the mainwindow from end to end?

How can I let the 2nd page of the `QStackedWidget` update its contents directly from the selected graph?

Is there an example I could see to understand what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the linked question, at this point you may be focusing on premature micro-optimizations. The smaller graph will be rendered on a much lower resolution, so it wouldn't look too good if you blow it up.

If it was your own custom widget with some complex drawing, you could easily draw onto a pixmap, then draw the big pixmap onto the big graph, and downscale it for the small graph. But then again, you'd be doing a whole lot of extra drawing for all those small graphs on the odd chance they get to the center position. You can optimize that, but will increase complexity.

It would still be possible to do it for `QCustomPlot`, but it won't be that easy, and I doubt the effort to do it will see worthy returns. So just create an extra big graph when you need it and don't worry about performance before you run into problems with it. The difference will be negligible, as graphs aren't too complex to draw. You won't be updating one graph from another, you will simply be using the same data set in two graphs.